# UITableView Cell different height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need a UITableView with different cell sizes. My approach was to work with the font. I have already worked out an example, but it does not work as I hoped.
I think the size of the cells could I change, but the text is not displayed.

My code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _quotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
               @"At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
               @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
               @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam",
               @"At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.", nil];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview: _tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate methods

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    size = [[_quotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                   sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    mytextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, size.height)];
    mytextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    mytextView.text = [_quotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return size.height + 50;

}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_quotes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        [cell addSubview:mytextView];

    }


    return cell;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Where Your textView is placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
mytextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, size.height)];
mytextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

mytextView.text = [_quotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

should go inside `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
like this:

```
if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    mytextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, size.height)];
    mytextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    mytextView.text = [_quotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:mytextView];

}
```

Comment: Also the `mytextView` variable should be local.

Comment: Thank you, the text is now in each cell and the cell has the right size. The UITextField with the text, however has not the right size. All the TextFields have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

```
mytextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, size.height)];
```

This code does not "get" your existing textview, it is making a new UITextView each time. This is the same text view you are trying to add later to your cell.